# GROUP BY adjacent records

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, gaps-and-islands

How to group a column by adjacent records in [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/lang.html)?

### Situation

[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a  12 table `JOIN`-ed `SELECT` query (grouped by multiple columns).

#### Table

Table `entity_log` storing `value` (over time; `timest` as Unix time timestamp):

```
CREATE TABLE entity_log (
   id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   timest INTEGER,
   entity INTEGER /*REFERENCES entity_table(id)*/,
   value  INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160703, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160704, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160705, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160706, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160707, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160708, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160709, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160710, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160711, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160712, 0, 0);
INSERT INTO entity_log (timest, entity, value) VALUES (1510160713, 0, 0);
```

#### Query

Chronologically-ordered `value` -occurrences, aggregated to `min(timest)` and `max(timest)` :

```
SELECT
   min(timest) AS timest_first,
   max(timest) AS timest_last,
   value
FROM
   entity_log
WHERE
   entity = 0
GROUP BY
   value
ORDER BY
   timest_last DESC
;
```

#### Result

If a certain `value` occurs repeatedly (but non-adjacent; `0,1,0` rather than `0,0,1`), then aggregated `timest` -ranges overlap:

```
timest_first  timest_last  value
........03    ........13   0
........05    ........10   1
```

### Objective

To further group `value` by chronologically-adjacent records:

```
timest_first  timest_last  value
........11    ........13   0
........05    ........10   1
........03    ........04   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly: What you want is a result that is dependent on the value in the next record. If the value of `value` is different, it starts a new subgroup. We can find the first row from the next group for every row. For that we can use an auto join, based on unequality. Of course the last row(s) of your data will go missing as they have no next row with a different `value`. (Maybe you could fix this by adding a fake row with future date and nonexisting `value` by using UNION.)

Then from this list of data where we know the starting date of the next group for each member, we can use that `Nextdate` for grouping so we can find the first and last date within that group as well:

```
SELECT Min(Somedate) AS timest_first, Max(Somedate) AS timest_last, value FROM
(SELECT  t2.Value, t2.timest AS Somedate, Min(t1.timest) AS Nextdate, t1.value as n
 FROM entity_log t1 JOIN entity_log t2
 ON t1.timest > t2.timest
 WHERE t1.value <> t2.value
 GROUP BY t2.timest) s1
GROUP BY value, Nextdate
ORDER BY 2 desc
```

Comment: "*What you want is a result that is dependent on the value in the next record. If the value of `value` is different, it starts a new subgroup.*" Correct. How would this work for multiple columns (`GROUP BY value, value2, ...`)?

Comment: You would get `WHERE t1.value <> t2.value OR t1.value2 <> t2.value2` etc.